# How to get the reachability/ status of an API?

Tags: c#, api

[.NET 4.7.2 WPF]

I am planning to send requests to an API which is on several machines, so I was thinking how I could check the status of the connection between the two machines, when my request looks like the below code?

So on my control app I would like to show a traffic light system of each IP e.g. 192.0.0.1:5555(GREEN avialable) 192.0.0.5:5555(Red not avialable)

I am sending to e.g.192.0.0.1:5555/data/Getname so I would like to know the connectivity before sending the command?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURIString);
request.UserAgent = "Test App";
request.Method = method;

if (body != "")
{
     p_CurrentAPIRequest = body;
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
}
else
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);

allDone.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Look up [HealthChecks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in .net - this is what theyre for.

Comment: @Jamiec thanks, and does this work for WPF C# app .Net 4.72, please?

Comment: First, why are you writing such code instead of HttpClient and `async/await`? You could replace all this code with `var response=await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);`. Second, HTTP is a connection-*less* protocol. There's no connection to check its status. What you can do is check whether those services are alive, by making a simple GET request. Quite often, services have a special URL you can call to get its status, eg `Healthy` or `Unhealthy`. In ASP.NET Core, that's provided by the HealthChecks middleware

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, your information is very invaluable, as this is a new domain for me. this is information I have peaced together online and it works so I will research using Http client, apart from http client seems allot simpler why else would you disregard HttpWebRequest?

Comment: HttpClient is thread-safe, reusable and can actually use a socket connection pool to reduce the overhead of establishing a new HTTP connection every time. With HttpWebRequest your code has to resolve the DNS name to an actual IP and open a TCP connection to it. DNS resolution can take up to 15 seconds. HttpClient on the other hand caches TCP connections (actually, network sockets) so once you've made a call to a URL you don't have to wait for DNS resolution again. This can still cause problems, eg if the actual IP changes. This is solved by using HttpClientFactory which takes care of recycling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The API is a Curl APi and they did not implement a health check would it be fround up on to check at an internal a simple end point to see the status of the connection, e.g every 100 milli seconds get the /ProjectName it its succeeds all is weel in fot it has issues?